# How to format spaces in IDEA JSON formatting for empty objects and arrays

Tags: json, intellij-idea, formatting, whitespace, empty-list

I have large JSON file with a lot of empty objects and arrays, but when i format this file in Intellij Idea it adds automatically spaces into all empty objects and arrays.

So, was:

```
{
  "someObject": {},
  "someArray": []
}
```

became:

```
{
  "someObject": { },
  "someArray": [ ]
}
```

and all other lines like this.

Since our team uses different editors/formatters for this file, i can't commit such changes, because this will be "formatting war" with other people on the same project, who use other editors for JSON.

In IDEA `Settings->Editor->Code Style->JSON` i found these settings:
[image: IDEA JSON formatting settings]

but looks like nothing about "empty object/array spaces".

So, the question is: ***is it possible to change default empty object/array formatting in JSON for Intellij IDEA?*** May be i can patch some formatter plugin or install other one for JSON?

Comment: The **objects** are handled by the **braces** and the *arrays* by the *brackets* shown in your screenshot (Spaces -> Within). By the looks of your settings it should not happen. Try adding an empty object/array in the demo area on the right of the window, and re-check/un-check the 2 checkboxes to see what happens. Also, which IJ version are you using? I have 14.1.7 and with the same setting as you've shown, it's working fine.

Comment: Hm, finally it works as you suggested. After checking in and back it works. Looks like it was temporary (cache?) issue. My IDEA is 2016.1.2. So, guess, just put your suggestion as an answer and i'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it was a hunch, a long-shot, etc that somehow there may have been a discrepancy between the actual settings and what was shown in the UI. Anyway, I'm glad I was able to help. Cheers mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment above, your settings look fine and I can confirm that on my local 14.1.7 installation they work as expected.

> but looks like nothing about "empty object/array spaces"

The settings which you are showing, `Editor -> Code Style -> JSON -> Spaces tab` are what your looking for:

- The `Braces` checkbox handles objects
- The `Brackets` checkbox handles arrays

You can add an empty object/array in the *preview* section on the right, and try to check/uncheck again those 2 checkboxes to see what happens:

[image: JSON Formatter settings]